# Can I make an alias for a node argument in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I am drawing illustrations with TikZ, the most common mistake I make is incorrectly writing the relative position of a node. I would for example write "left above" in stead of "above left". It is probably due to my native language where you would state "linksboven" when you indicate a position of an object.

Of course this is just a question of correcting and recompiling, but it remains a disturbing annoyance. Is it possible to make an alias for all those above|below left|right, so my document would simply compile when I write Dunglish TikZ?

Comment: `\tikzset{left above/.style={above left}}`

Comment: or better `\tikzset{linksboven/.style={above left}}`

Answer (score 2):

As [JLDiaz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/12571/jldiaz) and [percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3235/percusse) where pointing out, you can define styles for TikZ by the means of `\tikzset`. The principal mechanism is, that you can define a style and then set it content: `\tikzset{<my style>/.style={<content of my style>}}`.

So what you can do in your example is `\tikzset{left above/.style={above left}}` or `\tikzset{linksboven/.style={above left}}`.

Be aware however that you should not overwrite existing styles in that way.

Comment: I would rather suggest `\tikzset{left above/.style={above left={#1}}}`

Comment: ... or better `\tikzset{left above/.forward to=/tikz/above left}`